# docker swagger configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, swagger-ui

I'm following the instructions for using swagger-ui in docker from here - https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/installation/. I got swagger-ui working using docker compose but I have not been able to use my own swagger.json file by using the `SWAGGER_JSON` environment variable.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  swagger:
    build: ./swagger
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  environment:
    - SWAGGER_JSON=./swagger/swagger.json
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM swaggerapi/swagger-ui:latest
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 80/udp
```

It is still loading the default `https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json` definitions. How do I make it use my custom definitions?

Comment: Can you add your Dockerfile to your post, please?

Comment: added the dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The following is my docker file

```
FROM swaggerapi/swagger-ui:latest
LABEL maintainer="Ferd Tomale<beowulf1416@gmail.com>"

COPY ./swagger.json /usr/share/nginx/html/definitions/swagger.json

EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 80/udp
```